# What is the difference in meaning between these pairs of sentences, if any?

Tags: meaning, passive-voice, active-voice

What is the difference in meaning between these pairs of sentences, if any?

> He had his wallet stolen in Barcelona. (Active)
> His wallet got stolen in Barcelona. (Passive)
>
> Have you ever had your car broken into? (Active)
> Did your car ever get broken into? (Passive)
>
> He had his driving licence taken away (by the police) (Active)
> His driving licence got taken away (by the police) (Passive)
>
> They had their house burgled while they were on holiday (Active)
> Their house got burgled while they were on holiday (Passive)

Comment: This reads like a homework question. **We don't do homework,** even if some members of the community think it's on-topic. Please choose **one** pair to ask about (which is either the most representative, or the most troubling), explain why you have the answer you have, and ask about the **specific** aspect of your re-wording which you are unsure about.

Answer (score 1):

Each ***had*** form is an idiomatic active-voice form of the verb that's equivalent to the **passive-voice** form below it.

> They ***had*** their house burgled

means

> It happened to them that their house **was burgled**.

Notice that the the object of ***had*** cannot follow the past participle.

> They had burgled their house

means something entirely different, and in fact, is associated with a possible ambiguity in the original:

> They had their house burgled (for the insurance)

means

> They arranged for their house to be burgled (for the insurance).

Context is everything.